# Compile error on ESP8266 of working Arduino UNO Code - no matching function for

Tags: compiler-errors, arduino, esp8266, arduino-ide, nodemcu

Kindly help to solve this kind of error whenever I compile this error is shown - no matching function for call to 'IRsend::sendRaw(unsigned int [149], unsigned int, int&)'.I have tried the same code on the Arduino UNO where it is working fine but during compiling in nodemcu (ESP8266) it shows the following error

> no matching function for call to 'IRsend::sendRaw(unsigned int [149], unsigned int, int&)

Here is the code used:

```
#include <IRremoteESP8266.h>
#include <IRsend.h>

#define IR_SEND_PIN 4
IRsend irsend(IR_SEND_PIN);
int khz=38;
unsigned int ACoff[]={3026, 3044, 3032, 4304, 578, 1692, 550, 582, 550, 1706, 552, 712, 552, 580, 552, 1704, 552, 582, 552, 1838, 550, 582, 580, 566, 550, 582, 550, 714, 552, 582, 550, 582, 552, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 552, 582, 578, 1690, 552, 712, 552, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 552, 582, 550, 582, 578, 700, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 1838, 550, 582, 552, 580, 552, 582, 552, 712, 578, 568, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 714, 550, 1704, 552, 1706, 550, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 578, 566, 552, 582, 552, 712, 550, 582, 552, 580, 552, 1704, 552, 714, 550, 582, 552, 582, 578, 568, 550, 714, 552, 582, 552, 582, 550, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 552, 582, 552, 582, 578, 722, 552, 1706, 550, 582, 552, 1704, 552, 736, 552, 582, 550, 1704, 552, 1704, 552, 582, 580}; // UNKNOWN 9BB5B2B5
unsigned int ACon[]=  {3032, 3046, 3028, 4304, 576, 1692, 552, 582, 550, 1706, 550, 714, 550, 582, 552, 1706, 550, 582, 552, 1836, 552, 582, 578, 568, 552, 580, 552, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 552, 582, 550, 1836, 552, 582, 550, 582, 578, 1692, 550, 712, 552, 582, 552, 582, 550, 582, 550, 714, 552, 582, 550, 582, 552, 582, 578, 700, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 552, 1838, 550, 582, 552, 582, 552, 582, 550, 714, 578, 568, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 714, 552, 1706, 550, 1704, 550, 582, 552, 714, 550, 582, 578, 568, 550, 582, 550, 714, 552, 582, 550, 582, 550, 1706, 550, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 578, 568, 550, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 552, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 552, 582, 552, 582, 578, 722, 552, 1704, 552, 582, 550, 1706, 552, 736, 550, 584, 550, 1706, 550, 1706, 550, 1704, 578};// UNKNOWN 9BB5B2B5
unsigned int Temp16[]={3030, 3042, 3032, 4304, 576, 1694, 550, 582, 552, 1706, 550, 712, 552, 580, 552, 1706, 550, 582, 550, 1836, 550, 582, 578, 568, 552, 582, 552, 1834, 552, 582, 550, 1706, 552, 1706, 548, 714, 552, 580, 552, 582, 578, 1690, 552, 714, 550, 582, 552, 582, 550, 582, 552, 712, 550, 582, 550, 582, 552, 582, 578, 700, 550, 582, 552, 582, 552, 582, 550, 1836, 552, 582, 550, 584, 550, 582, 550, 712, 580, 568, 550, 582, 550, 584, 550, 712, 552, 1704, 552, 1704, 552, 580, 552, 714, 550, 582, 580, 566, 552, 580, 552, 712, 552, 582, 550, 582, 552, 1704, 552, 712, 552, 582, 550, 582, 580, 566, 552, 712, 552, 582, 552, 582, 550, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 578, 722, 550, 1706, 552, 582, 550, 1704, 552, 1860, 552, 1704, 552, 1704, 552, 582, 550, 582, 580}; // UNKNOWN F35ACDF0
unsigned int Temp17[] ={3030, 3042, 3032, 4306, 574, 1692, 550, 582, 550, 1704, 552, 712, 552, 582, 552, 1704, 550, 582, 550, 1836, 552, 582, 578, 568, 552, 1704, 552, 714, 550, 582, 550, 1706, 550, 1706, 552, 712, 550, 582, 552, 580, 578, 1688, 554, 712, 552, 582, 550, 582, 552, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 552, 582, 550, 582, 580, 698, 550, 582, 552, 582, 550, 582, 550, 1838, 552, 580, 550, 582, 550, 582, 552, 712, 580, 568, 550, 582, 550, 582, 552, 714, 550, 1704, 552, 1706, 552, 580, 552, 712, 550, 582, 578, 568, 550, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 552, 582, 550, 1704, 552, 714, 552, 582, 550, 582, 578, 568, 550, 714, 550, 582, 552, 582, 550, 582, 550, 714, 552, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 578, 722, 552, 1704, 552, 1706, 552, 582, 550, 738, 552, 1706, 552, 1706, 550, 582, 552, 582, 578}; // UNKNOWN 4046F041
unsigned int Temp18[] = {3030, 3070, 3004, 4304, 576, 1694, 552, 580, 550, 1706, 550, 714, 550, 582, 552, 1706, 550, 580, 552, 1836, 552, 582, 578, 568, 550, 1706, 550, 1838, 550, 580, 552, 1704, 552, 1706, 550, 712, 550, 582, 552, 582, 578, 1692, 552, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 552, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 578, 698, 552, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 552, 1836, 552, 580, 550, 584, 550, 582, 552, 712, 578, 568, 552, 582, 550, 582, 550, 712, 552, 1706, 554, 1702, 552, 580, 550, 714, 552, 582, 578, 568, 550, 582, 552, 712, 550, 582, 550, 582, 552, 1704, 554, 710, 552, 582, 552, 582, 578, 568, 552, 712, 552, 582, 550, 582, 552, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 580, 722, 550, 1704, 552, 1704, 552, 582, 550, 1862, 550, 1704, 552, 1704, 552, 582, 550, 582, 578}; // UNKNOWN 1575D184
unsigned int Temp19[] = {3030, 3046, 3028, 4306, 574, 1692, 552, 582, 550, 1706, 550, 714, 552, 582, 550, 1706, 552, 580, 552, 1836, 552, 582, 578, 1690, 552, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 550, 1706, 550, 1704, 552, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 580, 1690, 552, 712, 552, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 552, 582, 578, 698, 552, 582, 552, 582, 552, 582, 550, 1836, 552, 580, 552, 582, 552, 582, 550, 714, 578, 568, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 714, 550, 1706, 550, 1706, 550, 582, 552, 714, 550, 582, 580, 568, 550, 584, 550, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 1704, 552, 712, 550, 582, 550, 582, 578, 568, 550, 714, 552, 582, 552, 582, 550, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 552, 582, 578, 724, 550, 1708, 550, 1704, 552, 1704, 552, 736, 552, 1704, 552, 1706, 550, 582, 550, 582, 578};//Change it for your remote
unsigned int Temp20[] = {3030, 3044, 3030, 4304, 578, 1694, 550, 582, 552, 1708, 548, 714, 550, 582, 550, 1704, 552, 582, 550, 1838, 550, 582, 578, 1692, 550, 582, 550, 1836, 552, 582, 550, 1706, 550, 1704, 552, 712, 550, 582, 550, 582, 580, 1690, 552, 712, 552, 582, 552, 582, 550, 582, 552, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 578, 698, 552, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 552, 1836, 552, 582, 552, 582, 552, 580, 552, 714, 578, 568, 550, 582, 550, 582, 552, 712, 552, 1706, 550, 1704, 552, 582, 552, 712, 552, 582, 580, 566, 550, 582, 550, 714, 552, 582, 550, 582, 552, 1706, 550, 712, 552, 582, 550, 582, 578, 568, 552, 714, 550, 582, 552, 580, 552, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 552, 582, 550, 582, 580, 722, 550, 1706, 552, 1704, 552, 1706, 550, 1860, 550, 1704, 552, 1706, 550, 582, 550, 582, 578}; // UNKNOWN 3A9C4974
unsigned int Temp21[] ={3028, 3046, 3028, 4304, 576, 1694, 552, 582, 550, 1704, 552, 714, 550, 582, 552, 1704, 550, 582, 550, 1836, 552, 582, 578, 1690, 552, 1704, 552, 712, 550, 582, 550, 1706, 550, 1706, 552, 712, 550, 582, 552, 582, 578, 1690, 552, 714, 552, 580, 552, 582, 552, 582, 550, 712, 552, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 578, 698, 552, 582, 550, 584, 550, 582, 552, 1836, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 712, 578, 568, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 714, 552, 1706, 550, 1706, 552, 580, 550, 714, 550, 582, 580, 568, 550, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 1706, 552, 712, 550, 582, 550, 582, 580, 568, 552, 712, 550, 584, 550, 582, 550, 584, 550, 712, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 578, 722, 550, 582, 552, 580, 552, 582, 550, 738, 550, 1706, 550, 1704, 552, 582, 550, 582, 578}; // UNKNOWN 68B889BB
unsigned int Temp22[] = {3030, 3044, 3032, 4306, 574, 1694, 550, 582, 550, 1706, 550, 714, 550, 582, 550, 1704, 552, 582, 550, 1836, 552, 582, 578, 1692, 550, 1706, 550, 1838, 552, 582, 550, 1706, 550, 1706, 550, 712, 552, 582, 550, 582, 578, 1692, 550, 712, 552, 582, 550, 582, 552, 582, 550, 714, 552, 580, 552, 582, 552, 580, 580, 698, 552, 582, 550, 584, 550, 582, 552, 1836, 552, 580, 552, 582, 552, 582, 550, 714, 578, 568, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 714, 552, 1706, 550, 1706, 550, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 578, 568, 550, 582, 552, 712, 552, 582, 550, 582, 552, 1706, 552, 712, 550, 582, 550, 582, 578, 568, 550, 714, 550, 582, 552, 582, 550, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 550, 584, 550, 582, 580, 722, 552, 582, 550, 582, 552, 580, 552, 1860, 554, 1704, 552, 1704, 552, 582, 550, 582, 578}; // UNKNOWN F3CDEEA
unsigned int Temp23[] = {3030, 3044, 3030, 4304, 576, 1694, 550, 582, 550, 1704, 552, 714, 550, 582, 552, 1702, 552, 582, 550, 1836, 552, 1704, 578, 568, 550, 582, 552, 714, 550, 582, 552, 1704, 552, 1702, 552, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 578, 1690, 552, 714, 550, 582, 552, 582, 552, 582, 550, 714, 550, 584, 550, 582, 552, 582, 578, 700, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 1838, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 714, 578, 568, 550, 582, 552, 582, 552, 712, 552, 1704, 552, 1706, 550, 582, 550, 714, 552, 582, 578, 568, 552, 582, 550, 712, 552, 582, 550, 582, 552, 1706, 550, 712, 552, 582, 552, 582, 578, 568, 550, 714, 552, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 578, 722, 550, 582, 550, 582, 552, 1704, 552, 736, 552, 1706, 550, 1704, 552, 582, 550, 582, 580}; // UNKNOWN 74896B9A
unsigned int Temp24[] ={3032, 3042, 3032, 4306, 574, 1694, 550, 582, 550, 1706, 552, 714, 550, 582, 550, 1706, 550, 582, 550, 1836, 552, 1704, 580, 568, 550, 582, 550, 1836, 552, 580, 552, 1706, 550, 1706, 550, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 580, 1690, 552, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 552, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 552, 582, 550, 582, 578, 700, 552, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 1836, 552, 582, 550, 584, 550, 582, 550, 712, 578, 568, 550, 582, 552, 582, 550, 714, 552, 1706, 550, 1706, 550, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 578, 568, 550, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 552, 582, 550, 1704, 552, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 580, 568, 550, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 552, 580, 552, 714, 552, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 580, 722, 550, 582, 550, 582, 552, 1704, 552, 1860, 552, 1704, 552, 1702, 552, 582, 550, 582, 578}; // UNKNOWN F81A64E6
unsigned int Temp25[] = {3032, 3044, 3030, 4304, 578, 1692, 552, 580, 552, 1706, 552, 712, 550, 582, 552, 1704, 552, 582, 550, 1838, 550, 1704, 580, 568, 552, 1704, 552, 712, 550, 582, 550, 1706, 552, 1704, 550, 714, 552, 582, 550, 582, 578, 1692, 550, 714, 550, 582, 552, 580, 552, 582, 552, 712, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 578, 698, 550, 582, 552, 582, 550, 582, 552, 1836, 552, 580, 552, 582, 552, 580, 552, 714, 578, 568, 550, 582, 552, 580, 552, 714, 550, 1706, 552, 1704, 552, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 578, 568, 550, 582, 550, 714, 552, 582, 550, 582, 552, 1706, 550, 712, 552, 582, 550, 582, 580, 566, 550, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 712, 552, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 580, 722, 550, 582, 550, 1706, 550, 582, 552, 736, 552, 1704, 552, 1704, 552, 582, 552, 582, 578}; // UNKNOWN 3C198645
unsigned int Temp26[] ={3030, 3044, 3032, 4304, 576, 1694, 550, 582, 552, 1704, 552, 714, 550, 580, 552, 1706, 550, 582, 550, 1836, 552, 1704, 578, 568, 550, 1704, 552, 1838, 550, 582, 552, 1704, 550, 1704, 552, 714, 552, 580, 552, 582, 578, 1690, 550, 714, 552, 582, 550, 582, 552, 582, 550, 712, 552, 582, 550, 582, 552, 582, 578, 698, 552, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 1838, 552, 580, 552, 582, 550, 582, 552, 714, 578, 568, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 714, 552, 1704, 552, 1706, 550, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 580, 566, 552, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 1706, 550, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 578, 568, 550, 714, 552, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 552, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 578, 724, 550, 582, 550, 1706, 550, 582, 552, 1860, 550, 1704, 552, 1706, 550, 582, 552, 582, 578}; // UNKNOWN 11486788
unsigned int Temp27[] ={3032, 3046, 3028, 4306, 574, 1694, 550, 582, 550, 1706, 550, 714, 550, 582, 550, 1706, 550, 582, 552, 1836, 552, 1706, 578, 1690, 550, 582, 550, 714, 550, 584, 550, 1704, 552, 1706, 550, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 578, 1690, 550, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 552, 582, 550, 584, 578, 698, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 552, 1836, 552, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 552, 712, 578, 568, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 714, 550, 1706, 552, 1704, 552, 582, 552, 714, 550, 582, 580, 568, 550, 582, 552, 714, 550, 582, 552, 582, 550, 1706, 550, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 578, 568, 550, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 552, 580, 552, 582, 578, 722, 552, 582, 550, 1706, 552, 1706, 548, 736, 552, 1706, 550, 1706, 550, 582, 550, 582, 578}; // UNKNOWN 2900475E
unsigned int Temp28[] ={3032, 3044, 3030, 4304, 578, 1692, 550, 582, 552, 1704, 552, 712, 552, 582, 550, 1706, 552, 582, 550, 1836, 552, 1704, 578, 1692, 550, 582, 552, 1834, 554, 580, 550, 1706, 552, 1706, 550, 714, 552, 582, 550, 582, 578, 1688, 552, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 552, 582, 550, 714, 552, 582, 550, 584, 550, 582, 578, 698, 552, 582, 550, 582, 552, 582, 552, 1834, 554, 580, 552, 580, 552, 582, 550, 712, 580, 568, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 714, 550, 1706, 550, 1706, 550, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 578, 568, 552, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 552, 1704, 552, 712, 552, 582, 550, 582, 578, 568, 550, 714, 552, 582, 550, 582, 552, 582, 550, 714, 552, 582, 550, 582, 552, 582, 580, 722, 552, 580, 552, 1706, 552, 1704, 550, 1862, 550, 1704, 550, 1706, 550, 582, 552, 582, 580}; // UNKNOWN 357B0572
unsigned int Temp29[] = {3030, 3044, 3032, 4304, 578, 1692, 552, 582, 552, 1706, 550, 714, 550, 582, 550, 1704, 552, 582, 550, 1838, 550, 1704, 580, 1690, 550, 1706, 550, 712, 552, 582, 550, 1706, 550, 1706, 550, 714, 550, 582, 552, 580, 580, 1690, 550, 714, 550, 582, 552, 582, 550, 582, 552, 712, 550, 582, 552, 580, 552, 582, 578, 700, 550, 582, 552, 580, 552, 582, 550, 1836, 552, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 714, 578, 568, 552, 582, 550, 582, 550, 712, 552, 1706, 550, 1704, 552, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 580, 566, 550, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 552, 582, 552, 1704, 552, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 578, 568, 550, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 552, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 578, 722, 552, 1706, 550, 580, 552, 582, 550, 738, 552, 1706, 550, 1704, 552, 582, 550, 582, 578}; // UNKNOWN 460B741F
unsigned int Temp30[] = {3032, 3044, 3030, 4304, 576, 1694, 552, 582, 552, 1704, 550, 712, 552, 582, 552, 1704, 552, 582, 550, 1838, 550, 582, 578, 568, 550, 1706, 552, 712, 552, 582, 550, 582, 550, 1706, 550, 712, 552, 582, 550, 582, 578, 1690, 550, 714, 552, 580, 552, 582, 550, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 552, 582, 578, 698, 552, 582, 552, 582, 552, 1706, 550, 714, 552, 582, 550, 582, 552, 580, 552, 714, 578, 568, 550, 582, 552, 582, 550, 714, 550, 1706, 550, 1704, 552, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 580, 568, 550, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 550, 1706, 550, 582, 550, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 578, 568, 552, 714, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 582, 550, 712, 550, 582, 552, 580, 552, 582, 580, 722, 552, 1706, 550, 1704, 552, 1704, 552, 736, 552, 1704, 552, 582, 550, 584, 550, 1706, 578}; // UNKNOWN D8E205D1
//unsigned char ACoff[]=
//unsigned char ACon[]={"0xD22E7E7"};
//unsigned char Temp16[]={"0xF35ACDF0"};
//unsigned char Temp17[]={""}
void setup() {

irsend.begin();
}

void loop() {
  //On
 /* irsend.sendHaierAC(ACon,72);
  delay(2000);
  irsend.sendHaierAC(Temp16,72);
  delay(2000);
   irsend.sendHaierAC(Temp16,72);
  delay(2000);*/
 /* irsend.sendHaierAC(Temp17,72,38);
  delay(5000);
   irsend.sendHaierAC(ACoff,72,38);
  delay(5000);*/

/*  irsend.sendNEC(0xD22E7E78, 72);
    delay(2000);
    //16
     irsend.sendNEC(0xF35ACDF0, 72);
    delay(2000);
    //17
     irsend.sendNEC(0x4046F041, 72);
    delay(2000);
     //18
  irsend.sendNEC(0x1575D184, 32);
    delay(2000);
    //19
     irsend.sendNEC(0x5298AA30, 32);
    delay(2000);
    //20
     irsend.sendNEC(0x3A9C4974, 32);
    delay(2000);
    //21
     irsend.sendNEC(0x68B889BB, 32);
    delay(2000);
     //22
     irsend.sendNEC(0xF3CDEEA, 32);
    delay(2000);
     //23
     irsend.sendNEC(0x74896B9A, 32);
    delay(2000);
     //24
     irsend.sendNEC(0xF81A64E6, 32);
    delay(2000);
     //25
     irsend.sendNEC(0x3C198645, 32);
    delay(2000);
     //26
     irsend.sendNEC(0x11486788, 32);
    delay(2000);
     //27
     irsend.sendNEC(0x2900475E, 32);
    delay(2000);
     //28
     irsend.sendNEC(0x357B0572, 32);
    delay(2000);
     //29
     irsend.sendNEC(0x460B741F, 32);
    delay(2000);
     //30
     irsend.sendNEC(0xD8E205D1, 32);
    delay(2000);
    //off
     irsend.sendNEC(0x9BB5B2B5, 72);
    delay(2000);
*/

 delay(1000);
irsend.sendRaw(ACon, sizeof(ACon) / sizeof(ACon[0]), khz); delay(2000); //Send Signal to Turn On the AC 
  delay(2000);

      irsend.sendRaw(Temp17, sizeof(Temp17) / sizeof(Temp17[0]), khz);//Send Signal to Turn On the AC 
  delay(2000);
 irsend.sendRaw(Temp18, sizeof(Temp18) / sizeof(Temp18[0]), khz);  //Send Signal to Turn On the AC 
  delay(2000);
   irsend.sendRaw(Temp19, sizeof(Temp19) / sizeof(Temp19[0]), khz);  //Send Signal to Turn On the AC 
  delay(2000);
   irsend.sendRaw(Temp20, sizeof(Temp20) / sizeof(Temp20[0]), khz); //Send Signal to Turn On the AC 
  delay(2000);
  irsend.sendRaw(Temp21, sizeof(Temp21) / sizeof(Temp21[0]), khz); //Send Signal to Turn On the AC 
  delay(2000);
   irsend.sendRaw(Temp22, sizeof(Temp22) / sizeof(Temp22[0]), khz);  //Send Signal to Turn On the AC 
  delay(2000);
   irsend.sendRaw(Temp23, sizeof(Temp23) / sizeof(Temp23[0]), khz);//Send Signal to Turn On the AC 
  delay(2000);
   irsend.sendRaw(Temp24, sizeof(Temp24) / sizeof(Temp24[0]), khz);  //Send Signal to Turn On the AC 
  delay(2000);
   irsend.sendRaw(Temp25, sizeof(Temp25) / sizeof(Temp25[0]), khz);//Send Signal to Turn On the AC 
  delay(2000);
   irsend.sendRaw(Temp26, sizeof(Temp26) / sizeof(Temp26[0]), khz); //Send Signal to Turn On the AC 
  delay(2000);
   irsend.sendRaw(Temp27, sizeof(Temp27) / sizeof(Temp27[0]), khz); //Send Signal to Turn On the AC 
  delay(2000);
   irsend.sendRaw(Temp28, sizeof(Temp28) / sizeof(Temp28[0]), khz); //Send Signal to Turn On the AC 
  delay(2000);
   irsend.sendRaw(Temp29, sizeof(Temp29) / sizeof(Temp29[0]), khz);  //Send Signal to Turn On the AC 
  delay(2000);
   irsend.sendRaw(Temp30, sizeof(Temp30) / sizeof(Temp30[0]), khz);  //Send Signal to Turn On the AC 
  delay(2000);
   irsend.sendRaw(Temp16, sizeof(Temp16) / sizeof(Temp16[0]), khz);  //Send Signal to Turn On the AC 
  delay(2000);
     irsend.sendRaw(ACoff, sizeof(ACoff) / sizeof(ACoff[0]), khz);  //Send Signal to Turn On the AC 
  delay(2000);



}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a frustrating error on the ESP8266/ESP32 tool chains. You should start to use the explicit declaration like the library expects

```
void sendRaw(const uint16_t buf[], const uint16_t len, const uint16_t hz);
```

so change ALL

```
unsigned int ACoff[]={3026, ....};
....
unsigned int Temp30[] = {3032, ....};
```

to

```
uint16_t ACoff[]={3026, ....};
....
uint16_t Temp30[] = {3032, ....};
```

It compiles fine.

Comment: Please mark answer as accepted to close it and help others to find a solution. Thanks for thr feedback